# Intellij Filter target folder in Navigate Files

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I force IntelliJ to avoid searches in target folder.

For example:

If I navigate to File foo.properties I will have some target/.../classes/foo.properties
alongside the one .properties that I'm looking for

Comment: Output folders are excluded by default. Check that target folder is excluded `Project Structure` | `Sources`.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be excluded, but I still getting files from /target folder when I perform a search

Comment: Can you share a project that will reproduce this problem?

Comment: Sorry, it's a private repo at work